# Solution for eclipse project portability?

Tags: eclipse, portability

In my work env, I have setup the eclipse project in my PC which includes some Workspace Environment Variables, setting Project dependency and setting User library (from a common network location).

Now my fellow colleague who has checked out the same source code goes through same steps.
Is there a way to reduce this clutter ?

From what I could see is that only the source project location is different from my PC and other PC.

Is there any that I could change my project locations during eclipse startup in the other PC ?
So I could easily retain the same settings on another PC with same workspace.

Comment: is using maven an option?

Answer (score 1):

First steps:

- Use a version control system to store and share your projects.
- Check in everything that is contained in your workspace. That is not only your source code, but also the settings files in the hidden settings folder.
- Do not use Window -> Preferences to modify Java settings (or other build related settings). Instead always use Project -> Properties to modify build related settings.
- Never ever refer a network share or another location outside of your workspace. If you need a jar file which is currently on a network share, then check it into your version control system and afterwards check it out in your Eclipse workspace as local file.

Second step:

- Use Maven for project materialization, dependency and other management.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But the ways of work cannot be changed in my case.Hence, I'm trying to improve the case at my hand. Please comment if you have any possible solution for my problem.

Comment: All of the points listed under first steps can be done _by you_ independent of your work environment. Set up a git repository on a network share, put your code and settings into that, share that git repository with your colleague.